# Как записать данные в Excel-файл?

Tags: c#, excel

Как можно записать данные в документ Microsoft Excel?

Comment: Можно через обращение как OLE объект. погуглите на эту тему.

Answer (score 2):

- Я бы воспользовался бы сторонней библиотекой типа **http://epplus.codeplex.com** или, если это допустимо, записал бы данные в `.csv` файл. Подход с `OLE,` который вам рекомендуют считается ненадежным, из-за сложных внутренних механизмов `OLE dependency resolving` и из-за необходимости установленного `Excel` на машине пользователя.
- Если что, то **http://npoi.codeplex.com** давно не обновляется.
- Как вариант, можете обдумать возможность использования коммерческих компонентов с аналогичной функциональностью.

Answer (score 2):

Для формата xlsx (Начиная с Excel 2007) можно использовать `OpenXML` с обёрткой в виде `ClosedXML`, см. [ClosedXML - The easy way to OpenXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Так же как и в sql, только `OleDb`

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended      Properties=Excel 8.0", doc.FileName));
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "update [Лист1$] ...";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

Познакомиться с библиотекой [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться самым простым способом. Это записывать данные в файл CSV. Они читаются в excel.