# Библиотека для экспорта данных в Excel

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, excel, export

Собственно важна поддержка 2003 офиса, возможность задавать стили и типы данных ячеек.
Хотелось бы рассмотреть бесплатные библиотеки, но хорошие платные тоже подойдут(если за недорого). Использовать планируется в веб-приложении, построенном на паттерне MVC для экспорта табличных представлений в excel.

Answer (score 2):

Не так часто тут бывают повторы вопросов, однако:

[Как можно записать данные в excel?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/142577/c-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-excel)